# Delay when changing gradient on a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uibutton

I am placing two `CAGradientLayers` on a `UIButton`, and then changing the layers depending on whether the button is highlighted or not (finger down).

The problem is that it takes a fraction of a second for the gradient to change. At first it faded, i fixed that by clearing all animations on the layer.

Both gradients are created beforehand, and on touchDown the highlight gradient gets it hidden-variable set to FALSE, which i think should be instant? What have i missed? Is there a perhaps better way to accomplish this?

[Code is here](http://pastie.org/private/ejckzlst2qanntox4ejhw):

The purpose of the code is to create buttons like the Login button showed here:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `updateControlState` from UIButton's `setHighlighted` method instead of the `touchUp`: and `touchDown`. `setHighlighted` should be getting called automatically when touch events occur. I've done a button with `CAGradientLayers` like that before, and it may be faster than what your getting now.

```
-(void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted];
    [self updateControlState];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be due to the fact that all drawing is being made on the main thread. If the main thread is occupied by another source, the drawing will not be updated until the main thread calls the drawing function again.

I have been facing this problem when I was trying to update an `UIProgressBar` while parsing a XML File.  Obviously `NSXMLParser` runs on the main thread so my `progressBar` didnt update its progress until the parser has finished parsing. I had to call the

```
[bar setProgress:float]
```

like this:

```
[bar performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setProgress:) withObject:float];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good idea, but im not doing anything else in the main thread at the time im trying to change the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the properties of `CALayer` have implicit animation. `hidden` is one of them. You should do this to suppress the implicit animations –

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction disableActions];
[gradientLayerSelected setHidden:FALSE];
[CATransaction commit];
```